# Git rebase --onto squashed branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I need some help on how to use `git rebase --onto` to rebase a working branch effectively. I tried to follow this doc https://womanonrails.com/git-rebase-onto

### Context

I branched `branch-B` from `branch-A`. In the meantime `branch-A` was merged into `origin/main` and his commits were squashed to `I`.

```
Old situation                             Current situation
A---B---C---F---G---I (origin/main)       A---B---C---F---G---I (branch)
         \         /                               \
          D---E---H (branch-A)                      D---E---H---J---K (branch-B)
                  \                                 
                   J---K (branch-B)
```

### Expected result

I want to delete commits `D`,`E`,`H` and rebase on `I`

```
Expected result                                   
A---B---C---F---G---I (branch)
                     \
                      J'---K' (branch-B)
```

I don't know which commit I need to use on the third argument...

```bash
git rebase --onto origin/main HERE
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I remember it is as an English sentence:

> rebase (from) old_parent (up to) branch_tip onto new_parent

That is:

```
git rebase old_parent branch_tip --onto new_parent
```

(Note that the arguments are in a different order to how some people write them; the `--onto new_parent` is an option, not a positional argument, so can go anywhere, and I just find it more logical at the end rather than the beginning.)

In your case:

- `old_parent` is the commit hash shown on your diagram as `H`
- `branch_tip` is `branch-B` (and defaults to the currently checked out branch)
- `new_parent` is `I` AKA `origin/main`

So look up the actual commit hash for commit "H", and run:

```
git rebase H branch-B --onto origin/main
```

Or:

```
git switch branch-B
git rebase H --onto origin/main
```

Or if you prefer to put the `--onto` first:

```
git switch branch-B
git rebase --onto origin/main H
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a really helpful explanation to help me have a good understanding of it!